# Custom membership provider in web Applications

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I need to implement my own custom provider for Membership in my  web application. After implementing it partially successfully, I am looking for answers on below question:

- Which all function I need to override in my application
- Which all classes i need to inherit from. So far I used classes: MemberShipProvider, RoleProvider.
- Can the ASP.NET automatically connect to the correct table of my database. Is there any settings for this? like specifying the default table name ?
- Is there any Builtin function for setting the password as Salted Hash? OR I need to implement this on my own?
- the WAT Tool will be helpful for me still OR it will be limited in functionality, As i found that it may atleast help in debugging?

I found that some function i've missed to override  and also I think I did same with RoleProvider also. If there is any complete list OR so.. that's bound to help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Which all function I need to override in my application

You mainly need to override GetUser and ValidateUser in order for Membership Provider to work with Login Control. The rest are optional.

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{   
  public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

> 2) Which all classes i need to inherit from. So far I used classes:
>   MemberShipProvider, RoleProvider.

MembershipProvider is a must. If you want to authorize a user by roles, you need to implement RoleProvider.

> 3) Can the ASP.NET automatically connect to the correct table of my
>   database. Is there any settings for this? like specifying the default
>   table name ?

The reason you are overriding Membership Provider is you want to work with custom tables that you created. You are in charged of returning data from database; Membership provider no longer requires to know the name of your tables. Therefore, the answer is No - there is no setting.

> 4) Is there any Builtin function for setting the password as Salted Hash?
>   OR I need to implement this on my own?

Here are the methods that Membership Provider uses to generate hash password -

```
private static string GenerateSalt()
{
    byte[] numArray = new byte[16];
    (new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()).GetBytes(numArray);
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(numArray);
    return base64String;
}

private string EncodePassword(string pass, int passwordFormat, string salt)
{
    byte[] numArray;
    byte[] numArray1;
    string base64String;
    bool length = passwordFormat != 0;
    if (length)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
        byte[] numArray2 = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
        byte[] numArray3 = null;

        HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create(Membership.HashAlgorithmType);

        if (hashAlgorithm as KeyedHashAlgorithm == null)
        {
            numArray1 = new byte[(int) numArray2.Length + (int) bytes.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(numArray2, 0, numArray1, 0, (int) numArray2.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, numArray1, (int) numArray2.Length, (int) bytes.Length);
            numArray3 = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(numArray1);
        }
        else
        {
            KeyedHashAlgorithm keyedHashAlgorithm = (KeyedHashAlgorithm) hashAlgorithm;
            if (keyedHashAlgorithm.Key.Length != numArray2.Length)
            {

                if (keyedHashAlgorithm.Key.Length >= (int) numArray2.Length)
                {
                    numArray = new byte[(int) keyedHashAlgorithm.Key.Length];
                    int num = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        length = num < (int) numArray.Length;
                        if (!length)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        int num1 = Math.Min((int) numArray2.Length, (int) numArray.Length - num);
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(numArray2, 0, numArray, num, num1);
                        num = num + num1;
                    }
                    keyedHashAlgorithm.Key = numArray;
                }
                else
                {
                    numArray = new byte[(int) keyedHashAlgorithm.Key.Length];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(numArray2, 0, numArray, 0, (int) numArray.Length);
                    keyedHashAlgorithm.Key = numArray;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                keyedHashAlgorithm.Key = numArray2;
            }
            numArray3 = keyedHashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(bytes);
        }

        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(numArray3);
    }
    else
    {
        base64String = pass;
    }
    return base64String;
}
```

> 5) the WAT Tool will be helpful for me still OR it will be limited in
>   functionality, As i found that it may atleast help in debugging?

Yes, you can still use website administration tool, but it depends on those methods that you override.

*For example, if you do not override role provider, assigning a user to a role won't work.*

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider
http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/11/CreateCustomMembershipProviderASPNETWebsiteSecurity.aspx
http://www.shiningstar.net/aspnet_articles/customprovider/CustomProvider.aspx
http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29256/0/page/3
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050216.htm
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomMembershipProviders.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WSSecurityProvider.aspx

Comment: Appreciate the patience you had to answer my long list of Question. The Point 4 had been completely new to me. The links were helpful too.